# Linux Mint 20 Ulyana - Cannot Remove Directory that exists but doesn't exist

Tags: linux-mint, rm

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOiBk.png):[Cannot Delete Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOiBk.png)

I'm using Linux Mint 20 Ulyana. I created a directory:

mkdir ./VM_Shared

It won't allow me to access or even see the directory in file explorer.

I can see it with:

ls -al

But it won't allow me to remove it:

sudo rm -dir VM_Shared - directory doesn't exist
sudo rm -dir ./VM_Shared - directory doesn't exist
sudo rm ./VM_Shared - is a directory

I also tried them without sudo.

I'm at a loss here. I cannot figure out why it won't let me delete it or access it.

Comment: SOLVED: installed VMWare-Tools and rebooted. Folder was able to be deleted.

Comment: Hi @Phil, at StackOverflow, you can answer your own question and accept it instead of commenting on the question.